# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - Logging off

Tags: asp.net, authentication

How exactly can one implement a Log off function when using ASP.NET Forms Authentication on an intranet application?

How will this work if I am an administrator and want to log in "as someone else" into the application?

Please share your ideas

Comment: Why are you using forms authentication on an intranet application?  Why not use windows authentication?

Comment: At my previous job we didn't have any kind of Active Directory/LDAP solution, so we were forced to use Forms Authentication as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The preferred authentication for an intranet application is to use windows authentication instead of forms authentication.

In which case you can just log off of windows and login as "someone" else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to also add Session.Abandon() to ensure session data is purged as well